# IIS URL Rewrite for one spesific domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule that redirects users from **mydomain.com/reset/test123** to **mydomain.com/module.aspx?key=test123**.

The rule works fine, and look like this:

```
<rule name="Reset" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^reset/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/module.aspx?key={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

The only problem is that my website has multiple domains, and the rule runs for all of them. I need the rule to *only run for mydomain.com*.

I tried to change the match url to ^mydomain.com/reset/([_0-9a-z-]+), but this don't work.

How can I make the redirect to only run for one spesific domain?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition under your `<rule>` element:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
</conditions>
```

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved this issue :)